# Converet JSP drop down to Bootstrap drop down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm converting JSP page to Bootstrap page. This time I have to convert JSP drop down to Bootstrap drop down. I have already import bootstrap.min.css library. How to do this?

```
<s:select id="lookupType" cssClass="txtcontactname" name="lookupType"
       list="lookupTypeList"
       listKey="keyStr" listValue="valueStr"
       onchange="javscript:forms[0].submit()"/>
```

Thank you

Comment: Do u wanna add options manually? <option value="1">Option#1</option>

Comment: @ِAllloush No. values come from the back end

Comment: can u explain what do you want to achieve? you already have a list called 'lookupTypeList' so you need to spread the options of this list manually or you need only to apply bootstrap style on select tag?

Comment: @ِAllloush I need only to apply bootstrap style on select tag.. values of the drop down are lookupTypeList.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply bootstrap `form-control` you will have the select styled but the options will not take any style

If you want to change the style of options, you have to use a library for this

as an example, I usually use this library

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

it is very good and light one, in addition, the style is perfect

so what you need to do in your code, leave the JSP code as it is and add new class for the select, then add this JS code to initialise bootstrap select

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({//options})
```

Comment: @Mapa Don't forget to have a look at select2 also :)